# Apache with PHP configured as FastCGI and scripts without suffix

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have working FastCGI PHP inside Apache using mod_fcgid. But I noticed that PHP scripts are executed even without .php suffix specified.

Eg: if file is `mail.php` then `http://example.com/mail.php` and `http://example.com/mail` returns same output of PHP file `mail.php`

Is this common behaviour? And should be this (execution without suffix) disabled?

my Apache configuration is:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
<Directory "{WwwRoot}">
    Options -Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    FCGIWrapper {ConfigsRoot}/fcgi-php5 .php
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

with simple wrapper

```
#!/bin/sh
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=2000
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
/usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

Thanks.

Comment: As @LazyOne said, this behavior is up to you, but it may behoove you to leave it, as you can use /mail/ instead of /mail.cgi to hide the fact that you're using CGI, and also, may get better SEO outta such a configuration.    IF your example were real estate listings. you'd have /listings/NY/Albany/ instead of /listings.cgi?st=NY&city=Albany

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this common behaviour?

It's your specific settings.

**Solution:** `Options -MultiViews`

**[Apache Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#negotiation)** says (you will have to scroll down a bit):

> The effect of **MultiViews** is as follows: if the server receives a
>   request for */some/dir/foo*, if */some/dir* has MultiViews enabled,
>   and */some/dir/foo* does **not** exist, then the server reads the
>   directory looking for files named `foo.*`, and effectively fakes up a
>   type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media
>   types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for
>   one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's
>   requirements.

---

> And should be this (execution without suffix) disabled?

Up to you.  By default such behaviour is disabled.

Comment: Aaaa... Thanks!! I searched manual of mod_fcgid but totally forget about common apache directives.. THANKS!